# Reach an element from different class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I created a simple activity like this.

```
public class AppleActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        textview.setText("This is Apple tab");
        examp myexam = new examp(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

And i added second simple class in my project like this;

```
public class examp{
Context context;

public examp(Context cntxt){
this.context = cntxt;
   }
}
```

Here is my question. How can i reach AppleActivity's textview from my examp class?? Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it helps :=)

```
file MyActivity.java:
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView myView ;
    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
            Points myPoints = new Points(this);
            myPoints.displayMsg("Hello World !!!");
    }  
    }
    --------------------------------------------------------------

    file Points.java:
    private class Points {
        protected MyActivity context;
        //add a constructor with the Context of your activity
        public Points(MyActivity _context){
            context = _context;
        }

        public void displayMsg( final String msg){
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    context.myView.setText(msg);    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pass activity instead of activity's context??